# Why is momentum-based scrolling not working on iPad when launched from home screen?

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, touch

I added smooth 'momentum-based' scrolling on iPad on a website using the following CSS:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

This works perfectly when browsing within Safari browser.

However if I then 'Add to Home Screen' and launch from there in full-screen the scrolling is not smooth (as if that CSS was not added).

Any thoughts please?

Comment: Which iOS version are you testing?

Comment: iOS 10.3.3 version

Comment: it is online somewhere for debuggin?